# Jquery .attr('class') does not return inherited parent classes

Tags: jquery, class, inheritance

Using Jquery 1.6.4.

I'm attempting to use css to give my app a clue as to the context of a user action by applying classes prefixed with `context-` at each layer of my UI.

So for a user clicking on something in the 'search' div I could assign the class 'context-userContext-search' and then everthing within that div would return that context when I call $(this).attr('class') and so on and so forth down to the most descriptive context flags being applied to the element itself.

I'm doing this specifically to avoid having the define the entire heirarchy for each target element that needs it.  But.. it doesn't work.

My html:

```
<div class="context-userContext-search">
    <table>
        <thead class="context-layoutContext-tableHeader">
            <tr class="context-userContext-search">
                <th id="search_A2655_header" class="clickable sortable ui-state-highlight dialog_right_menu context-objectAttribute-A2655 context-objectClassName-host" value="A2655">
                    Hostname
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I call `$('#search_A2655_header').attr('class')` it returns this:

`clickable sortable ui-state-highlight dialog_right_menu context-objectAttribute-A2655 context-objectClassName-host`

When I expected it to return this:

`context-userContext-search context-layoutContext-tableHeader clickable sortable ui-state-highlight dialog_right_menu context-objectAttribute-A2655 context-objectClassName-host`

These classes of course do not exist within any stylesheets but I do not recall them having to for inheritance to work.

I could walk up the tree with `.parents('[class^="context-"]')`, but that is not nearly as cool and probably expensive.

Alternate methodologies to accomplish my goal are welcome.

Comment: Well OBVIOUSLY it's not going to return the parent elements classes since you haven't asked for them. Elements don't 'inherit' the parent classes in the sense of having them as properties. You have to step up the tree to find them.

Comment: To drive the point home, classes are defined by HTML, not CSS. There is no notion of inheritance in HTML; that is a concept of CSS.

Comment: I suspect there may be a better way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do. Classes at heart are a CSS concept designed for styling, although there are certainly perfectly valid other use cases, but in your case you seem to be trying to use them as some form of identification of elements--to reiterate @xdazz's question, why? To put it another way, once you get back your huge list of all classes of ancestors what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: I'm sending it up via ajax on right click so I can return a context aware menu. All that works. Applying tags via .data() works. I figured using classes would be a nice shortcut if they inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
var classes = 
  $('#search_A2655_header')
    .parentsUntil('.context-userContext-search')
    .andSelf()
    .attr('class')
```

**EDIT:**

I've been trying this on my own and doesn't seem to work. Try with this instead:

```
var getAllClasses = function (from, until) {
  var cs = []
  $(from)
    .parentsUntil(until)
    .andSelf()
    .each(function(){
      if (this.className)
        cs.push(this.className)
    })
  return cs
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/3tR93/

Comment: I was too quick with my answer tried it and it didn't seem to work. See edit

Comment: Given I always end in a form and don't care about extra spaces, I used this from your example.  `var classes = '';$(this).parentsUntil('form').andSelf().each(function() { if ( this.className ) classes = classes + this.className + ' ';});`  Works.  Thank you.